# Cannot delete files

Tags: files, permissions, delete

I am tidying up my back up drive

```
root@raspberrypi:/media/pi/Seagate Expansion Drive/Jane-PC# ls -la | grep Goo
drwx-w--w- 1 pi pi    4096 Nov 17  2016 Google Calendar - Month of Nov 2016_files
-rw------- 1 pi pi  673696 Nov 17  2016 Google Calendar - Month of Nov 2016.htm
root@raspberrypi:/media/pi/Seagate Expansion Drive/Jane-PC# chmod 777 Google\ Calendar\ -\ Month\ of\ Nov\ 2016_files/
```

changed permissions

```
root@raspberrypi:/media/pi/Seagate Expansion Drive/Jane-PC# ls -la | grep Goo
drwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi    4096 Nov 17  2016 Google Calendar - Month of Nov 2016_files
```

down a  folder and list an example file

went down a directory and list an example

```
root@raspberrypi:/media/pi/Seagate Expansion Drive#  ls -l  | grep Jane-
drwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi   24576 Jun 20  2018 Jane-PC
root@raspberrypi:/media/pi/Seagate Expansion Drive/Jane-PC# cd Google\ Calendar\ -\ Month\ of\ Nov\ 2016_files/
root@raspberrypi:/media/pi/Seagate Expansion Drive/Jane-PC/Google Calendar - Month of Nov 2016_files# ls -l | grep rsA
-rw------- 1 pi pi 137650 Nov 17  2016 rsAA2YrTtjxqe5r5aTKPlGbDLVedABH8C6Lw
-rw------- 1 pi pi 315600 Nov 17  2016 rsANwU0p4TXBrw57nAJSu_NbEilyn1-9G5yA
```

tried changing attributes

```
root@raspberrypi:/media/pi/Seagate Expansion Drive/Jane-PC/Google Calendar - Month of Nov 2016_files# chmod 777 rsAA2YrTtjxqe5r5aTKPlGbDLVedABH8C6Lw 
chmod: changing permissions of 'rsAA2YrTtjxqe5r5aTKPlGbDLVedABH8C6Lw': Operation not supported
root@raspberrypi:/media/pi/Seagate Expansion Drive/Jane-PC/Google Calendar - Month of Nov 2016_files# chown root:root rsAA2YrTtjxqe5r5aTKPlGbDLVedABH8C6Lw 
chown: changing ownership of 'rsAA2YrTtjxqe5r5aTKPlGbDLVedABH8C6Lw': Operation not supported
```

find the inode  and try and delete it

```
root@raspberrypi:/media/pi/Seagate Expansion Drive/Jane-PC/Google Calendar - Month of Nov 2016_files# ls -li | grep rsAA2YrTtjxqe5r5aTKPlGbDLVedABH8C6Lw 
87770 -rw------- 1 pi pi 137650 Nov 17  2016 rsAA2YrTtjxqe5r5aTKPlGbDLVedABH8C6Lw
root@raspberrypi:/media/pi/Seagate Expansion Drive/Jane-PC/Google Calendar - Month of Nov 2016_files# find . -inum 87770  -exec rm -i {} \;
rm: remove regular file './rsAA2YrTtjxqe5r5aTKPlGbDLVedABH8C6Lw'? y
rm: cannot remove './rsAA2YrTtjxqe5r5aTKPlGbDLVedABH8C6Lw': Operation not permitted
```

so what next ?

Comment: What filesystem does your Seagate Expansion Drive use? I experienced similar problems with a device that has the NTFS filesystem. Have you tried the `-f` option of the `rm` command (be careful though that `-f` and `-i` are not compatible: `-f` will NOT ask you if you really want to remove a file). You can try `sudo rm`: as the superuser you should be able to bypass permissions (I'm not completely sure of it, though). You could also try to use the `mv` command to move the file somewhere else and then delete it from there. Note: be careful when you use the `rm` command as "undo" is not an option

Comment: its NTFS. But it seemd to be working OK until I had to replace the micro SD card that the pi was using

Comment: but when I plug it into a win10 machine , I can delete the folder .

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

fixed it